# How to limit django admin inline formsets using a specific field from inline

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

I have a table B with 1 to n relationship with A. In B I have this field:

```
type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=1, choices=STATUS)
```

With these status:

```
DRAFT = 'd'
SUBMITTED = 's'
ACCEPTED = 'a'
PUBLISHED = 'p'
STATUS = (
    (DRAFT, _('Draft')),
    (SUBMITTED, _('Submitted')),
    (ACCEPTED, _('Accepted')),
    (PUBLISHED, _('Published')),
```

I want to limit the inline formset to only one option for draft, accepted and published, and no limit for submitted. How can I do this?

Comment: Make a custom widget/form then

Comment: I think a custom widget/form isn't enough. I'll probably need some javascript, but I don't know how to do it. I'm googling for an answer.